# Stepper in tableView, unrecognized selector sent

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to get value from the stepper which is made in prototypecells. Unfortunately, when trying to return to the sender, he gets an error:

[stepperChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

```
class SettingsSetsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepperSets: UIStepper!
    
}

class ViewControllerSettingsSets: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

@IBAction func stepperChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
        //
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
       
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StepSet", for: indexPath) as! SettingsSetsTableViewCell


}
```

Im changed on:

```
cell.stepperSets.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
        let pointInTable = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.tableView)
        let cellIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable)
  
    }
```

It works. But is this the correct and safe way to get cellIndexPath and value stepper?

Comment: This means that the @IBAction you've hooked up in the interface builder has a different signature than the function in your code. Perhaps you've renamed the `stepperChanged` function in your code? Just remove the old connection in IB and connect the new one instead.

Comment: Im edited post for explain. thanks.

Comment: If the unrecognized selector is solved, the question is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

cell.stepperSets.tag = indexPath.row
cell.stepperSets.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stepperValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)

}

@objc func stepperValueChanged(step:UIStepper) {
 print(step.tag) // step.tag value is an indexpath of your cell
        
}
```